# Set non-required fields from django.contrib.auth.User on Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a custom registration form on Django, my Model looks like that:

```
#models.py

class UserRegister(models.Model):

   user = models.ForeignKey(User)

   GENDER_CHOICES = (
       ('M', 'Male'),
       ('F', 'Female'),
       ('O', 'Other'),
   )

   birthday = models.DateField(null = False, blank=False)

   gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=False)
```

I was reading about models.User and I saw that first_name and last_name are optional and email is not unique. I need that first_name and last_name be required attributes and email be unique in my database, how can I do that?

Thank you.

EDIT 1:
If I inherit the model from User, my code would be like this?

```
#models.py
class UserRegister(User):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )
    birthday = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

EDIT2:
I solved my problem, what I did was copy `AbstractUser` from `django.contrib.auth.models` into my `models.py` and changed the fields to be required. After that I edited my `settings.py` adding AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myApp.MyModelName' to it.

Here is the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 3):

The django model fields are default to be `NOT NULL`

And if you want it allow `NULL` values, use `null=True` parameter.

If you want it allow empty value ('' but not null), use `blank=True` parameter.

And if you want that field to be unique, set `unique=True`

```
class UserRegister(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
```

---

Maybe I misunderstood you question, you want to modify the User model fields.

And because you just can't update the User model declaration, if you want to do so, you have the following choices:

1. Make other fields to hold it, outside the `user` field.
2. Inherits the model from `User`, not use combination, then override the field.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. However, I'm trying to use the django.contrib.auth.User since this class provides me username, first_name, last_name, email and password (hash) fields. I'd like to use it, but I need to change first_name and last_name to be required and e-mail to be unique.

Comment: So, if I inherits the model, it would be like this? How can I use it to create the form? Is it creates the table in database or I have to do something more?
class UserRegister(User):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Other'),
    )
    birthday = models.DateField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

Comment: @AlexandreLara Because the `User` Model don't have an `abstract = True` in its Meta class, so if you inherit the model from it, it will generate a new table with the extra field that doesn't have in the super Model

Comment: Are you saying that will be generated two tables or just one? My code is right now? (I edited my first post with the new code)

Comment: It's not working, it gives me an error: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Local field 'first_name' in class 'UserRegister' clashes with field of similar name from base class 'User'

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change what attributes are required or if you need other data about a user, I would suggest writing your own user model instead another model that links to Django's. Docs are here, it's not too difficult: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model